Covariance for two correlated Ornstein Uhlenbeck processes
Given two Ornstein Uhlenbeck stochastic differential equations:
$$
dX^1_t = \theta_1(X_t^1 - \mu_1)dt + \sigma_1 dW^1_t
$$
$$
dX^2_t = \theta_2(X_t^2 - \mu_2)dt + \sigma_2 dW^2_t
$$
Where $W^1_t$ and $W^2_t$ are two correlated brownian motions with constant instantaneous correlation:
$$
Corr(dW^1_t,dW^2_t) = \rho
$$
And their instantaneous covariance:
$$
Cov(dW^1_t,dW^2_t) = \sigma_1 \sigma_2 \rho
$$
The terminal or integrated covariance at time $T$ can be written as
$$
Cov(X_T^1,X_T^2) = \int_{0}^{T} \sigma_1 \sigma_2 \rho dt = \sigma_1 \sigma_2 \rho T
$$
However, I am confused at this point. From what I understand, multi-dimensional OU processes are jointly stationary as $t \to \infty$. However, from the terminal covariance above, this seems to not be the case as the processes seem to be unstable as time progresses. Could someone please help me understand if the terminal covariance derivation above is correct?

Your notation is unusual. If $W_t^1$ and $W_t^2$ are correlated with constant $\rho$ we write
$$\text{d}W_t^1 \text{d}W_t^2 = \rho \ \text{d}t$$
Why? Well Itô's product rule implies
\begin{aligned}
\text{d}\left( W_t^1 W_t^2 \right) &= W_t^1 \ \text{d}W_t^2 + W_t^2 \ \text{d}W_t^1 + \text{d}W_t^1 \ \text{d}W_t^2 \\
&= W_t^1 \ \text{d}W_t^2 + W_t^2 \ \text{d}W_t^1 + \rho \ \text{d}t
\end{aligned}
so we can conclude
$$W_t^1W_t^2 = \int_{0}^t W_s^1 \ \text{d}W_s^2 + \int_0^t W_s^2 \ \text{d} W_s^1 + \rho t$$
and then
$$\mathbb{E}\left[ W_t^1 W_t^2 \right] = \rho t \implies \rho = \frac{\mathbb{E}\left[ W_t^1 W_t^2 \right]}{t} = \frac{\mathsf{cov}\left[ W_t^1, W_t^2 \right]}{\sqrt{\mathsf{var}\left[ W_t^1 \right]} \sqrt{\mathsf{var}\left[ W_t^2 \right]}}$$
which is the standard definition of correlation between two random variables $W_t^1$ and $W_t^2$. If I understand your derivation, you observe $\text{d}X_t^1 \text{d}X_t^2 = \sigma_1 \sigma_2 \rho \ \text{d}t$ and claim
$$\mathsf{cov}\left[ X_t^1, X_t^2 \right] \overset{\text{claim}}{=} \int_0^t \sigma_1 \sigma_2 \rho \ \text{d}s = \sigma_1 \sigma_2 \rho t$$
While I agree with the premise, the conclusion does not follow. In particular,
$$\mathsf{cov}\left[ X_t^1, X_t^2 \right] \neq \int_{0}^t \text{d}X_s^1 \text{d} X_s^2$$
To find $\mathsf{cov}\left[ X_t^1, X_t^2 \right]$ we must compute
$$\mathsf{cov}\left[ X_t^1, X_t^2 \right] = \mathbb{E}\left[ X_t^1 X_t^2 \right] - \mathbb{E}\left[ X_t^1 \right] \mathbb{E}\left[ X_t^2 \right]$$
According to Wikipedia we have $\mathbb{E}\left[ X_t^1 \right] = \mu_1$ and $\mathbb{E}\left[ X_t^2 \right] = \mu_2$ so it only remains to compute $\mathbb{E}\left[ X_t^1 X_t^2 \right]$. By Itô's product rule
\begin{aligned}
\text{d}\left( X_t^1 X_t^2 \right) &= X_t^1 \text{d} X_t^2 + X_t^2 \text{d}X_t^1 + \text{d}X_t^1 \text{d} X_t^2 \\
&= X_t^1 \Big ( \theta_2 \left( X_t^2 - \mu_2 \right) \text{d}t + \sigma_2 \ \text{d}W_t^2 \Big ) + X_t^2 \Big ( \theta_1 \left( X_t^1 - \mu_1 \right) \text{d}t + \sigma_1 \ \text{d}W_t^1 \Big ) + \sigma_1 \sigma_2 \rho \ \text{d}t
\end{aligned}
so
$$\mathbb{E}\left[ X_t^1 X_t^2 \right] = \mathbb{E} \left[ \int_0^t X_s^1 \theta_2 \left( X_s^2 - \mu_2 \right) \text{d}s \right] + \mathbb{E}\left[ \int_0^t X_s^2 \theta_1 \left( X_s^1 - \mu_1 \right) \text{d}s \right] + \sigma_1 \sigma_2 \rho t$$
but I don't see an easy way to simplify this.
EDIT: Here is a full derivation of $\mathsf{cov}\left[ X_t^1, X_t^2 \right]$. The trick is to use the analytic solution of an OU process when computing the covariance.

Thanks @msantama. I was under the impression that the integrated covariance at $t$ is equal to the "true" covariance of the two processes at $t$. But I guess this is inaccurate. I am wondering what is the usefulness of the integrated covariance?

By integrated covariance I suppose you mean $\int_0^t \mathsf{cov}\left[ \text{d}X_s^1, \text{d}X_s^2 \right] \ \text{d}s$. You would have to define for me $\mathsf{cov}\left[ \text{d}X_s^1, \text{d}X_s^2 \right]$. When I write $\text{d} X_t^1 \text{d} X_t^2 = \sigma_1 \sigma_2 \rho \ \text{d}t$ this is notation for the well-defined expression of the covariation $\int_0^t [ X^1, X^2]_s \ \text{d}s = \sigma_1 \sigma_2 \rho t$. Does $\mathsf{cov}\left[ \text{d}X_s^1, \text{d}X_s^2 \right]$ have a rigorous meaning?

Frankly I've never seen something like $\mathsf{cov}\left[ \text{d} X_s^1, \text{d} X_s^2 \right]$ so I'm not sure what meaning it conveys.
